# Should "the belief that the world was round" be "the belief that the world is round" in this sentence?

Tags: tense, reported-speech

There is a text like this,

> "The belief that the world was round was not strange to Columbus."

I think 'the world was' should be fixed like 'the world is'.
Because 'the world is round' is the truth of all time.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

With a timeless property like that, your version (with *is*) is possible; but it is not usual.

The habit in English of converting the tense of reported speech in the past ("He believed 'It is round'" => "He believed it *was* round") is so strong, that it tends to overcome logical objections like yours.

Comment: What is the common usage of this sentence, 'was' or 'is'? And What is the proportion of the use of 'was' and 'is' in this case?

Comment: Probably 7 to 1 in favor of *was*.

Comment: The GloWbE corps has 32 instances of "that the world _is_ round" against 29 of "that the world _was_ round". But only about 8 of the 32 are in the past - most of them are things like "we can demonstrate that the world is round" which are present anyway. So excluding that, we get something like 29:8 in favour of "was" - rather lower (in this case) than  Clare's figure (though I have no idea where she got that from).